# Cannot connect remotely to SQL Server running in Docker container

Tags: sql, sql-server, docker, azure-data-studio

I have a SQL Server running in a docker container on my unRaid machine, based on the official [Microsoft SQL Server image](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) with the unRaid template. I can connect to this server through an unRaid Docker template.

The container starts fine, and I can access the server locally through the unRaid machine's terminal. I would like to be able to connect to this server remotely from my Apple Silicon Mac, using Azure Data Studio, however I persistently get the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
> The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Attached is a screenshot of the credentials I am attempting to use to log in, but the error suggests a network issue, not a credential issue. I have checked that remote connections are enabled in SQL Server.

[Connection Details in Azure Data Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlOY9.png)

How can I go about troubleshooting this? The logs from the docker container do not show any connection attempts, but I'll paste them below

```
2023-12-12 17:22:47.04 spid26s     Database 'model_replicatedmaster' running the upgrade step from version 938 to version 939.
2023-12-12 17:22:47.39 spid26s     Database 'model_replicatedmaster' running the upgrade step from version 939 to version 940.
2023-12-12 17:22:47.77 spid26s     Database 'model_replicatedmaster' running the upgrade step from version 940 to version 941.
2023-12-12 17:22:48.13 spid26s     Database 'model_replicatedmaster' running the upgrade step from version 941 to version 942.
2023-12-12 17:22:48.47 spid26s     Database 'model_replicatedmaster' running the upgrade step from version 942 to version 943.
2023-12-12 17:22:49.61 spid26s     Database 'model_replicatedmaster' running the upgrade step from version 943 to version 944.
2023-12-12 17:22:50.00 spid26s     Database 'model_replicatedmaster' running the upgrade step from version 944 to version 945.
2023-12-12 17:22:50.33 spid26s     Database 'model_replicatedmaster' running the upgrade step from version 945 to version 946.
2023-12-12 17:22:50.67 spid26s     Database 'model_replicatedmaster' running the upgrade step from version 946 to version 947.
2023-12-12 17:22:51.00 spid26s     Database 'model_replicatedmaster' running the upgrade step from version 947 to version 948.
2023-12-12 17:22:51.33 spid26s     Database 'model_replicatedmaster' running the upgrade step from version 948 to version 949.
2023-12-12 17:22:51.68 spid26s     Database 'model_replicatedmaster' running the upgrade step from version 949 to version 950.
2023-12-12 17:22:52.01 spid26s     Database 'model_replicatedmaster' running the upgrade step from version 950 to version 951.
2023-12-12 17:22:52.59 spid26s     Database 'model_replicatedmaster' running the upgrade step from version 951 to version 952.
2023-12-12 17:22:52.99 spid26s     Database 'model_replicatedmaster' running the upgrade step from version 952 to version 953.
2023-12-12 17:22:53.34 spid26s     Database 'model_replicatedmaster' running the upgrade step from version 953 to version 954.
2023-12-12 17:22:53.71 spid26s     Database 'model_replicatedmaster' running the upgrade step from version 954 to version 955.
2023-12-12 17:22:54.04 spid26s     Database 'model_replicatedmaster' running the upgrade step from version 955 to version 956.
2023-12-12 17:22:55.11 spid26s     Database 'model_replicatedmaster' running the upgrade step from version 956 to version 957.
DBSTARTUP (model_replicatedmaster, 32762): FileMgrPreRecoveryTime took 104 ms
DBSTARTUP (model_replicatedmaster, 32762): InitPersistentVersionStoreTime took 165 ms
DBSTARTUP (model_replicatedmaster, 32762): InitalizeForScansTime took 208 ms
DBSTARTUP (model_replicatedmaster, 32762): PhysicalCompletionTime took 488 ms
DBSTARTUP (model_replicatedmaster, 32762): RemapSysfiles1Time took 195 ms
DBSTARTUP (model_replicatedmaster, 32762): StartupInDatabaseTime took 14354 ms
DBSTARTUP (model_replicatedmaster, 32762): UpgradeTime took 14158 ms
2023-12-12 17:22:57.32 spid26s     [32761]. Feature Status: PVS: 0. CTR: 0. ConcurrentPFSUpdate: 1. ConcurrentGAMUpdate: 1. ConcurrentSGAMUpdate: 1, CleanupUnderUserTransaction: 0. TranLevelPVS: 0
2023-12-12 17:22:57.32 spid26s     Starting up database 'model_msdb'.
2023-12-12 17:22:58.49 spid26s     Converting database 'model_msdb' from version 927 to the current version 957.
2023-12-12 17:22:58.49 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 927 to version 928.
2023-12-12 17:22:59.29 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 928 to version 929.
2023-12-12 17:23:00.04 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 929 to version 930.
2023-12-12 17:23:00.47 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 930 to version 931.
2023-12-12 17:23:00.83 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 931 to version 932.
2023-12-12 17:23:01.17 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 932 to version 933.
2023-12-12 17:23:01.86 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 933 to version 934.
2023-12-12 17:23:02.21 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 934 to version 935.
2023-12-12 17:23:02.59 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 935 to version 936.
2023-12-12 17:23:02.97 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 936 to version 937.
2023-12-12 17:23:03.31 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 937 to version 938.
2023-12-12 17:23:03.82 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 938 to version 939.
2023-12-12 17:23:04.26 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 939 to version 940.
2023-12-12 17:23:04.62 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 940 to version 941.
2023-12-12 17:23:05.02 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 941 to version 942.
2023-12-12 17:23:05.37 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 942 to version 943.
2023-12-12 17:23:06.40 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 943 to version 944.
2023-12-12 17:23:06.79 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 944 to version 945.
2023-12-12 17:23:07.31 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 945 to version 946.
2023-12-12 17:23:07.78 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 946 to version 947.
2023-12-12 17:23:08.13 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 947 to version 948.
2023-12-12 17:23:08.49 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 948 to version 949.
2023-12-12 17:23:08.88 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 949 to version 950.
2023-12-12 17:23:09.25 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 950 to version 951.
2023-12-12 17:23:09.98 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 951 to version 952.
2023-12-12 17:23:10.37 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 952 to version 953.
2023-12-12 17:23:10.74 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 953 to version 954.
2023-12-12 17:23:11.09 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 954 to version 955.
2023-12-12 17:23:11.44 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 955 to version 956.
2023-12-12 17:23:12.21 spid26s     Database 'model_msdb' running the upgrade step from version 956 to version 957.
DBSTARTUP (model_msdb, 32761): FileMgrPreRecoveryTime took 102 ms
DBSTARTUP (model_msdb, 32761): InitPersistentVersionStoreTime took 253 ms
DBSTARTUP (model_msdb, 32761): InitalizeForScansTime took 280 ms
DBSTARTUP (model_msdb, 32761): PhysicalCompletionTime took 326 ms
DBSTARTUP (model_msdb, 32761): RemapSysfiles1Time took 424 ms
DBSTARTUP (model_msdb, 32761): StartupInDatabaseTime took 15076 ms
DBSTARTUP (model_msdb, 32761): UpgradeTime took 14651 ms
2023-12-12 17:23:14.15 spid46s     Attribute synchronization initialized
2023-12-12 17:23:14.15 spid46s     Attribute synchronization manager initialized
2023-12-12 17:23:14.15 spid26s     Resource governor reconfiguration succeeded.
2023-12-12 17:23:14.15 spid26s     SQL Server Audit is starting the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2023-12-12 17:23:14.18 spid26s     SQL Server Audit has started the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2023-12-12 17:23:14.22 spid26s     XE session 'system_health' started.
2023-12-12 17:23:14.55 spid26s     XE session 'telemetry_xevents' started.
2023-12-12 17:23:14.65 spid26s     SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login "sa".
2023-12-12 17:23:14.94 spid26s     Server name is '28e434a10b45'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2023-12-12 17:23:14.95 spid29s     Clearing tempdb database.
2023-12-12 17:23:14.95 spid75s     Always On: The availability replica manager is starting. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2023-12-12 17:23:14.95 spid78s     [4]. Feature Status: PVS: 0. CTR: 0. ConcurrentPFSUpdate: 1. ConcurrentGAMUpdate: 1. ConcurrentSGAMUpdate: 1, CleanupUnderUserTransaction: 0. TranLevelPVS: 0
2023-12-12 17:23:14.95 spid79s     [5]. Feature Status: PVS: 0. CTR: 0. ConcurrentPFSUpdate: 1. ConcurrentGAMUpdate: 1. ConcurrentSGAMUpdate: 1, CleanupUnderUserTransaction: 0. TranLevelPVS: 0
2023-12-12 17:23:14.95 spid75s     Always On: The availability replica manager is waiting for the instance of SQL Server to allow client connections. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2023-12-12 17:23:14.95 spid78s     Starting up database 'msdb'.
2023-12-12 17:23:14.96 spid79s     Starting up database 'StackOverflow'.
2023-12-12 17:23:14.96 spid79s     RemoveStaleDbEntries: Cleanup of stale DB entries called for database ID: [5]
2023-12-12 17:23:14.96 spid79s     RemoveStaleDbEntries: Cleanup of stale DB entries skipped because master db is not memory optimized. DbId: 5.
2023-12-12 17:23:15.13 spid79s     Parallel redo is started for database 'StackOverflow' with worker pool size [4].
2023-12-12 17:23:15.56 spid26s     Parallel redo is shutdown for database 'StackOverflow' with worker pool size [4].
2023-12-12 17:23:17.14 spid29s     [2]. Feature Status: PVS: 0. CTR: 0. ConcurrentPFSUpdate: 1. ConcurrentGAMUpdate: 1. ConcurrentSGAMUpdate: 1, CleanupUnderUserTransaction: 0. TranLevelPVS: 0
2023-12-12 17:23:17.14 spid29s     Starting up database 'tempdb'.
2023-12-12 17:23:17.67 spid29s     The tempdb database has 1 data file(s).
2023-12-12 17:23:17.73 spid75s     The Service Broker endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
2023-12-12 17:23:17.73 spid75s     The Database Mirroring endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
2023-12-12 17:23:17.77 spid75s     Service Broker manager has started.
2023-12-12 17:23:18.08 spid26s     Recovery is complete. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2023-12-12 17:27:40.34 spid51      XE session 'telemetry_xevents' stopping.
2023-12-12 17:27:40.55 spid51      XE session 'telemetry_xevents' started.
2023-12-12 17:29:29.64 spid51      Attempting to load library 'xplog70.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2023-12-12 17:29:29.70 spid51      Using 'xplog70.dll' version '2022.160.4095' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_msver'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2023-12-12 17:31:18.30 spid51      Using 'dbghelp.dll' version '4.0.5'
2023-12-12 17:41:25.37 spid51      XE session 'telemetry_xevents' stopping.
2023-12-12 17:41:25.50 spid51      XE session 'telemetry_xevents' started.
```

I have tried restarting the container, setting and resetting "allow remote connections", and pinging the IP/port combination with `telnet {host.ip} 1433`. In this case, connection was refused.

Comment: How was the container launched? e.g.: if you used a `docker run` line did you remember to include `-p 1433:1433` to publish the container's tcp/1433 port on the host's tcp/1433 port?

Comment: Aside... your screen shot shows you are attempting to connect to `192.168.1.34,1443`. That is not port `1433`.

Comment: ahh, typo. The error persists with 192.168.1.34,1433 as well. i launched the container through the unRaid template GUI, which as I understand it just fills in a docker run command and executes it based on the values in the template. In any case, i verified in portainer that 1433 is published to 1433 in the container/host.

Comment: Via a terminal on the unRaid, what does `netstat -antp` output? If the Local Address is showing `127.0.0.1:1433` it has only published the port on the `localhost` address, which would be why you cannot connect from a remote machine.

Comment: Here's [the output from netstat](https://pastebin.com/sRN4bRtM) for the sql server process. The only IP under which port 1433 is published is 127.0.0.1, do you know how to correct this?